# Store and use application configuration settings in database for a Grails application?

Tags: grails, configuration, grails-orm

we currently use configuration files to store application settings. I was wondering if it is possible to store these settings inside the database and if so how to achieve this?

Greetings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store whatever you want in the database and read it out using a Domain class.  This is especially useful if you want to be able to make changes to things without having to redeploy new code.  But realize that you will incur a database hit every time the property is accessed.

You can set up a ConfigurationService with:

```
ConfigurationService {
    static def configurationValues

    def getConfigurationValues() {
        if(configurationValues == null) {
            refreshConfigurationValues()
        }
        configurationValues
    }

    def refreshConfigurationValues() {
        configurationValues = //go get the values out of the database
    }
}
```

Then you can add a Controller/Action to force the refresh when necessary

```
ConfigurationController {

    def configurationService

    def refreshConfiguration = {
        configurationService.refreshConfigurationValues()
        render "Ahhh... That's refreshing :)"
    }
}
```

Now you can refresh your config values by invoking: "http://yoururl/appName/configuration/refreshConfiguration"

Comment: In my case there a a bunch of configuration settings that i would prefer to have inside the database. For example a username/password combo used for sending out emails, a secret password that is used to encrypt a hash etc.. I know that i can cache specific domain classes but as you state i want to reinitialize the cache whenever i make changes to the configuration and skip the database hit whenever possible.

Comment: But that's what Jarreds proposal does.

Comment: @david I added the code to provide an example for Marco's comment above.

Answer (score 1):

This is can be done with BootStrap.groovy. So following Jarred's answer, create a domain class of the configuration data you would like to store and then inside the BootStrap.groovy file, put these values. What this does is if the configuration values does not exists, it will create it, if it exists will not do anything.

Then you can access your configuration values using the domain class. I'm assuming you want to do this because grailsApplication.config... can sometimes become unruly.

Domain-Class MyConfig.groovy:

```
class MyConfig {
  String type
  String name
  String value
}
```

BootStrap.groovy:

```
def myConfig = MyConfig.findByName("path") ?: new MyConfig(
    type: "Path"
    name: "path"
    value: "/var/tmp"
).save(failOnError: true)
```

Comment: I agree that the initialization of this can be done in the BootStrap.groovy.  But creating your config options there wouldn't solve the problem because you would have to deploy new code in order to change any values.  Which is the same pitfall as using the Config.groovy.  Plus you'd have to wrap everything with determining which environment you're in (which isn't hard) but basically the same as what the Config.groovy provides.